# Prevent "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when expanding all Nodes when using the Angular Material nested tree view

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's Nested TreeView for a project with a large dataset.

Although a Flat TreeView might be better for handling large data, switching isn't possible due to my reliance on the nested structure.

Generally, it works well, but expanding all nodes recursively causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded" errors. I need a way to know when all nodes are expanded. I've tried several methods, including promises, without success.

Does anyone know how to verify that all nodes have been expanded?

```
  expandAllNodes() {
    this.recursivelyExpandNodes(this.dataSource.data);
    console.log('done'); 
  }

  recursivelyExpandNodes(nodes: TreeNode[]) {
    nodes.forEach(node => {
      this.treeControl.expand(node);
      if (node.children) {
        this.recursivelyExpandNodes(node.children);
      }
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: That error nomally means that you have created infinite recursion, I would assume this is also the case here, although there's not enough information in the question to debug it fully.

Comment: *"large dataset"* large (as in width) *should* be fine. What's the depth of the tree?

Comment: Assuming this is due to the data being large and not bad recursion logic or node references, the typical solution is just to get rid of the recursion and maintain a stack yourself. Take a node, and push all its children to a list, then expand that node. Then take a node from the list, and push all it's children and expand it. Then take a node from the list, and push all it's children and expand it. Then take a node... Repeat until the list is empty.

Comment: you might have a circular reference. maintain a set of nodes that have been expanded. before you make the recursive call, make sure you haven't already expanded that node.

Comment: @Anna please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging